# Multivariate Metropolis Hasting using PyMC

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pymc, pymc3, mcmc

I am working on Parameter estimation using Metropolis-Hasting algorithm in Python (I am very new to Python). I have around 8 input parameters to estimate.

I referred to the PyMC documentation, the first step is to define a 'model' and pass it to the MCMC() method. How do I go about creating a 'model' in PyMC assuming a normal distribution for each parameter? Also, the values for the parameters need to be varied only by +\- 50% of their default values, How can I specify this in the model? should this be the standard deviation for that variable?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're using PyMC -- if you are starting out, I would use PyMC3 instead, which is the current, maintained version of the project.  You might also get better responses if you posted what you had tried so far!

Comment: are u still interested by an example ?